# How to change color of action editior an graph editor selected items

Tags: animation

This image is screenshot of my problem:

[image: enter image description]

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with better screenshots in future.

Answer (score 3):

This colour is influenced by the bone groups color theme. After you change it you'll have to exit the action editor and re-enter (i.e. hovering over the action editor and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> 2 times, to update the colors).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.92 (and 2.93.2), the option to show Bone Group colors in the Action Editor, Dopesheet, and Graph Editor has been buried in the Blender Preferences. You need to go to Edit > Preferences > Animation > F-Curves, and check "Channel Group Colors". Hopefully this setting can eventually be moved back to the "View" menu of the Action Editor, where it used to reside. I hope this helps!

Info from Blender devs: https://developer.blender.org/T87884

[image: Bone Group Colors in Action Editor Blender 2.93]